# I am trying to click on a category and products will show accordingly, but its not working

Tags: laravel

Controller:

```
public function shopfront(){
$products=Product::all();
$categories=Category::all();
return view('shop.index',compact('products','categories'));
}
```

index.blade.php:

```
<div class="sidebar-widget">
<h4 class="pro-sidebar-title">Categories</h4>
<div class="sidebar-widget-list mt-30">
<ul>
@foreach ($categories as $category)
@foreach ($products as $product)
@if ($category->id==$product->category->id)
<li>
<div class="sidebar-widget-list-left">
<input type="checkbox"> <a href="">{{ $category->name }}
{{-- <span>4</span> --}}
</a> 
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</div>
</li>  
@endif
@endforeach
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I do not know how to achieve this, will highly appreciate some help or i sample that i can work with
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1pnn.png)

Comment: what you see when you show it on browser?

Comment: why you don't use eloquent relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know how you want to achieve it but let me give you an idea if you want it in this way:
when click on a category then it should show all products of that category:

in your **blade** file

```
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('category.products',$category->name)}}">  {{$category->name}}</a>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

you should create a route named `category.products` as below in **web.php**

```
Route::get('category/{name}','YourController@yourmethod')->name('category.products');
```

**controller**

```
public function CategoryProducts($name){
    $category = Category::where('name',$name)->first();
    $products = $category->products;
    return view('front-end.categoryWise-products',compact('products'));
}
```

you can customize it according to your requirements.

Comment: How can i achieve this on input checkbox, if i wanna check a category and see the products according to the category

Comment: you can do it using ajax call than, when checkbox is checked then pass the name of the category to ajax call and in success you show all that products through javascript.